# C++ CodeBlock Issue With Vector In Array

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm unable to modify a vector inside the vector array using CodeBlock 20.03. Here's the "reduced" version of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

vector<int> neighbor_fields[500000];
int main()
{
    neighbor_fields[0].push_back(0);

    return 0;
}
```

The program runs fine, but there's an error displayed after program finishes ***"Terminated with status -1073741510"***. I've done some research and this script seems like it is perfectly legal in C++.

I think is is an issue related to CodeBlock/compiler(gcn gcc) because it compiles fine on elsewhere.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I've corrected the code(it should be an array of vectors instead of a single vector). Another interesting thing is doing a push_back on a single vector also terminates with that error code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

vector<int> neighbor_fields;
int main()
{
    neighbor_fields.push_back(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not a compiler bug. There is some memory fault when the program runs.

Comment: This does not compile. There's no array here. Double check the full output when trying to compile.

Comment: This shouldn't compile. If it does that's extremely concerning. With clang I get `member reference base type 'std::__1::__vector_base<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::value_type' (aka 'int') is not a structure or union
    neighbor_fields[0].push_back(0);` which is the correct outcome.

Comment: I've made a mistake in copying the code, it is corrected now. It should be an array of vectors instead of a single vector.

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling the code as C++ instead of C?  How do you configure what compiler command is executed?

Comment: Copied from CodeBlock Console: `g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -std=gnu++17 -c "C:\[shortened_path]\test.cpp" -o obj\Debug\test.o`

`g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\CPlusPlus.exe obj\Debug\main.o obj\Debug\test.o 
`

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [cppreference:vector operator[]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at), accessing a nonexistent element through this operator is undefined behavior.

For your case, `neighbor_fields[0]` means that it access the first element of the vector, which is nonexistent and resulting in the error.

it should be: `neighbor_fields.push_back(0);`

Comment: It's also an `int` which doesn't have `push_back` so I'm not sure how this code compiled in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 misunderstanding in this code:

1. when you declare `neighbor_fields` you create a container but you are not putting anything in it. So if you try to access to an item of the container you are gonna get an undefined behavior, if you want to make the program safer you can use `std::vector::at`, it works like `std::vector::operator[]` but when the index is out of range throw an exeption so you can handle it.
2. `std::vector::operator[]` return a reference to a variable of the type stored by the container, in our case `int`, you can not use `push_back()` on a int variable but you use it for adding items at the container.
   The code you are looking for is

   std::vector neighbor_fields;

   int main() {

   ```
     neighbor_fields.push_back(0); 

     return 0;
   ```

   }

this code create a container and add the value 0. You can assume that a std::vector is like a c-like arrays so `int array[10]`, but is possible change the size adding and erasing items.

I'm sorry for the code but I can't mark it us code